# Не работает curl запрос

Tags: python-3.x, curl, fastapi

вот мой curl запрос:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"id": 1, "item": "cxcadasdas"}"
```

в ответе же я получаю:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body",1],"msg":"Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)","type":"value_error.jsondecode","ctx":{"msg":"Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes","doc":"{id: 1, item: cxcadasdas}","pos":1,"lineno":1,"colno":2}}]}
```

в чем проблема? везде стоят двойные кавычки

Comment: ваш код на пайтоне не покажете?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2BvsCiyP это первый модуль, https://pastebin.com/k7TLejZ3 это второй

Comment: 'везде стоят двойные кавычки' и что не так?

Comment: в ответе я получаю ошибку , почитайте вопрос

Comment: Хоть я не разбираюсь в curl и fastap, мне кажется что запрос должен быть таким `curl -X 'POST' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"id": 1, "item": "cxcadasdas"}'`

Comment: тогда я получаю вот такой ответ:  {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Comment: curl -X 'POST' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo' -H 'accept:application/json' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"id":1,"item":"cxcadasdas"}'

Comment: Теперь такой ответ:  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: '127.0.0.1. Сервер у меня запущен и работает.

Comment: ну, пробуй `curl -X "POST" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo" -H "accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"id\": 1, \"item\": \"cxcadasdas\"}"`

Comment: Заработало, объясни пожалуйста в чем причина? экранировать кавычки получается надо? почему именно в теле запроса?

Comment: "экранировать кавычки получается надо?" да. Есть тоже самое на пайтоне.

Comment: Просто книгу по FastAPI читаю там автор про это ничего не говорит, мне так кажется это проблема только curl запросов, на пайтоне можно replace воспользоваться. Спасибо, вопрос закрыт.